# How to replace the old Rotate2D in the recent versions with RotationTransform

Tags: geometry

I have a very old code and I am trying to Evaluate it with a recent version (10.0.0.0). I used `Rotate2D` and now it must be replaced by `RotationTransform`. Here one statement I used:

```
Pr[r_,a_]=Graphics[Line[{Rotate2D[r + a, -θ, {0, 0}],Rotate2D[r + 3 a, -θ, {0, 0}]}]];
```

How can I rewrite using `RotationTransform`?

Comment: does `Graphics[Rotate[Line[{r + a, r + 3 a}], -θ, {0, 0}]]`work?

Comment: .. or `Graphics[GeometricTransformation[Line[{r + a, r + 3 a}], 
  RotationTransform[-θ, {0, 0}]]]`?

Comment: Unfortunately, both are not working. You can try it for  `a=r=1`

Comment: Abdullah, does the original code `Rotate2D[r + a, -\[Theta], {0, 0}]` work when `a=r=1`? I think the first argument is supposed to be a vector (see [this search result](https://books.google.com/books?id=VnH0UzTycTcC&pg=PA131&lpg=PA131&dq=mathematica+rotate2d&source=bl&ots=yhx1dkPwHF&sig=ocFZdKH4KxxAMV5wEus3dBnLjHQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxkPvQl7bdAhVjGjQIHUgtDGsQ6AEwCHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=mathematica%20rotate2d&f=false))

Comment: ... see also  [wolfram reference page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/Geometry/Rotations.html)

Comment: Yes, you are right, **r** here is a vector `r={x,y}`, sorry for the confusion. Yeh, it was working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Graphics[Rotate[Line[{r + a, r + 3 a}], -θ, {0, 0}]]
```

and

```
Graphics[GeometricTransformation[Line[{r + a, r + 3 a}], RotationTransform[-θ, {0, 0}]]]
```

both work.

**Reference:** [`` Geometry`Rotations ``](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/Geometry/Rotations.html)